# Search array for object of provided type

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, generics

I have an array of Animals. I want to search it for a certain sub-class type. The array of Animals will only ever contain one of each sub-class type. I have tried the following, which does not work. I get a compile error, stating: "animalType is not a type".

```
public static func getAnimal<T: Animal>(animalType: T.type) -> Animal {
    for animal in self.animals {
        if animal is animalType {
            return animal
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible in Swift?

I would want to call it as such...

```
AnimalServices.getAnimal(Dog)
```

Comment: You could do an if let cast as a type and if it fails then the animal is not of that type

Comment: I just tried that. "if let a = animal as animalType { }" The compiler still complains that animalType is not a type. Am I botching the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simplified example, notice I return an optional Animal since the search may fail (the compiler does not know that you will always have just one animal of that type):

```
class Animal {
    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Cat: Animal {
    init() {
        super.init(name: "Cat")
    }
}

class Dog: Animal {
    init() {
        super.init(name: "Dog")
    }
}

struct Zoo {
    static var animals: [Animal] = []

    static func getAnimal<T: Animal>(animalType: T.Type) -> Animal? {
        for animal in animals {
            if animal is T {
                return animal
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

Zoo.animals.append(Cat())

Zoo.getAnimal(Cat) // Returns the cat as optional
Zoo.getAnimal(Dog)
```

Simply put, `T` is your generic type. `T.Type` state that your are passing a T type as parameter.

Comment: I was close. ;) This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Or as a nice one-liner: `return animals.filter { $0 is T }.first`. Although less performant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the identity operator `===` to check if the type of the array element is equal to the generic type:

```
if animal.dynamicType === animalType {
    return animal
}
```

Comment: No you can't. The compiler will throw an error: "binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Animal.Type' and 'T'"

Comment: @blacksquare you must be doing something wrong - it works perfectly in a storyboard, and moreover I'm not using `T` in that code snippet...

Comment: I just tested your code in swift 1.1 and it works. I was testing using swift 1.2 and it threw an error--so beware in the future. I'm using the syntax I'm using to compare against the returned string values, which is a valid comparison because they're both Strings. In any of event the best answer to the question is to simply check against `is T`.

Comment: Your solution worked, I preferred @Matteo Piombo's though. Thanks!

Comment: @lionpants: Yeah I agree, that's the correct way of doing it

Comment: @blacksquare I tested on 1.2 right now and it seems to work - and as stated above I agree with your last statement :)

Comment: you're right--I apologize. Once I reloaded playground it stopped throwing that error. I originally had your example using equality `==` and then switched it over to identity `===`--it must have been some xcode bug carrying over. ugh. what can you do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `is` or `as` syntax with an unknown type. The sort of type reflection you're looking for can be done using NSObject's `kindOfClass` method so long as `Animal` is a subclass of `NSObject`:

```
class Animal: NSObject {

    class func getAnimalOfType<T: Animal>(animals: [Animal], animalType: T.Type) -> Animal? {
        for animal in animals {
            if animal.isKindOfClass(animalType) {
                return animal
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}

class Zebra: Animal { }
class Whale: Animal { }
var animals = [Zebra(), Whale()]
Animal.getAnimalOfType(animals, animalType: Zebra.self)
```

If `Animal` isn't a subtype of `NSObject`, you could always do this--but it seems a little hacky to me:

```
 if "\(animal.dynamicType)" == "\(animalType)" {
      return animal
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Test<T: Hashable> {

    static func test(t: Any) {
        println(t is T)
    }
}

Test<Int>.test(3)
```

In this example I am passing the type (Int in my case, animalType in yours) to the struct and the variable (my Int(3), your animal) as a parameter of the static function test. I used T: Hashable, you will want to test with T: Animal.